# How can I get either true or false on a database find in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, find, boolean

How do I get either true or false on a database find in Rails?

Say if I have a database with username field and a password field. I want to find a certain username in my database and return true if I found it or false if I didn't. I'm a noob and I tried googling it but could not find anything.

ex.

```
q = User.new
q.username = "Joe"
q.password = "password"

User.find_by_username("Joe") -> true
User.find_by_username("Admin") -> false
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
User.exists?(:username => "Joe")
```